# Magento 2: Move place order button from payment to sidebar on checkout page?

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs, place-order

I want to move the place order button from the payment to sidebar on checkout page.

[image]

Anyone can give me a suggestion?

*Edit*: **Is this even possible *(with the answer/approach provided)*?**

From my research every payment method has its own .html template including an own button. This button is not loaded from a knockout.js template. E.g. a part of the "free" payment method:

```
    <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action primary checkout"
                    type="submit"
                    data-bind="
                    click: placeOrder,
                    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                    ">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

While the "check / money order" payment method looks like this (only differences are `enable: (getCode() == isChecked())` but hey, there still are differences and there is no "1 almighty general place order button":

```
  <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action primary checkout"
                    type="submit"
                    data-bind="
                    click: placeOrder,
                    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                    enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                    "
                    disabled>
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The answer provided only moves the aggreements which results in something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi - did you find a reasonable way of doing this in the end? Thanks

Comment: How did you find success in the checkbox  validation of the terms and conditions?

Answer (score 9):

I had the similar requirement to change the place order button at the bottom of the summary block. Since there is place order button assigned to each payment method. I have created a custom place order button next to order summary block. While clicking on the button I have triggered the place order button of the selected payment method.

Step 1:

Create a `checkout_index_index.xml` file in

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/layout path

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendorName_PlaceOrder::css/place_order_button.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PlaceOrder/js/view/summary</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PlaceOrder/summary</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2:

Create a file `summary.html` in the path

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/web/template

```
<div class="opc-block-summary" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Order Summary'" class="title"></span>
    <!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- ko if: (isVisible()) -->
<div class="actions-toolbar-trigger" id="place-order-trigger-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="button action primary" id="place-order-trigger" value="Place Order" >
        <span>Place Order</span>
    </button>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Step 3:

Create a file `summary.js` in the path

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/web/js/view

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    ],
    function(
        $,
        ko,
        Component,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            isVisible: function () {
                return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
            },
            initialize: function () {
                $(function() {
                    $('body').on("click", '#place-order-trigger', function () {
                        $(".payment-method._active").find('.action.primary.checkout').trigger( 'click' );
                    });
                });
                var self = this;
                this._super();
            }

        });
    }
);
```

Step 4:

To hide the default place order button use CSS file as follows

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/web/css/place_order_button.css

```
.payment-method-content .actions-toolbar{
    display: none;
}
```

Attached is the screenshot!

[image]

Comment: Hello @Haritha, I have tried your solution but it's not working. Button not showing on checkout page. Can you please help me on this.?

Comment: Hi  Mayank Zalavadia, Can you check if your custom module is loaded after Magento_Checkout Module in app/etc/config.php

Comment: I already check that and now it's working but I am not able to add Place Order button as you mention in your screenshot. It displays only in the summary. Can you Please help me to move Place Order button at the same place as you mention in your screenshot.

Comment: Can you share your screenshot?

Comment: http://nimb.ws/5EdgS2 check screenshot

Comment: Hi @Haritha, I have How did you get the selected payment method while clicking the place order button

Comment: Hi sri, This code provides the selected / active payment method while clicking the place order.
$(".payment-method._active").find('.action.primary.checkout').trigger( 'click' );

Comment: Hi @Haritha, I have created  single place order button for all the payment methods as you have said, but it is working only for customer, If i entered as a guest, while clicking the place order, It shows the the error (It is failed to get the shipping info)

Comment: @Haritha thanks mate this is a good solution and works well with M2.4.4

Answer (score 1):

at first you need create checkout_index_index.xml in your theme, then need disable item before-place-order in 314 line:

```
 <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
```

with:

```
<item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Then you need re-add that element on the end of your Checkout, after place order button, like this:

```
<item name="after-place-agreements" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/payment/before-place-order</item>
</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="agreementss" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Then copy in your default template(html) after place order:

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after-place-agreements') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

All these answer are not complete because missing registration.php file for register module

This is the best answer i found.

https://github.com/davidroberto/magento2-place_order_sidebar

Here is complete module you need only  to place under App/code
and to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command

Hope this help!!!

Comment: thanks, It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that the sidebar is hidden in the **mobile view**.

To see the sidebar customer need to click on the **minicart**.

This can confuse the customer when he will not be able to quickly find the **Place Order** button.

Hiding is implemented in the following file with `custom-slide` class:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/sidebar.html`

```html
<div id="opc-sidebar"
     data-bind="afterRender:setModalElement, mageInit: {
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
        'type': 'custom',
        'modalClass': 'opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper',
        'wrapperClass': 'checkout-container',
        'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom',
        'responsive': true,
        'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
        'overlayClass': 'modal-custom-overlay',
        'buttons': []
    }}">

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('summary') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->

    <div class="opc-block-shipping-information">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shipping-information') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I made `VCT Place Order Sidebar (Button Lösung)` module on Magento Marketplace that implements this task for mobile view as well.