# Moving place order button + terms and conditions checkbox after payment methods

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom, magento2.2.3, terms-and-conditions

I've been trying to place the order button and terms and conditions checkbox beneath the payment method section during the checkout procedure. Now, I've followed this:

[Magento 2 - move terms and conditions position in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/magento-2-move-terms-and-conditions-position-in-checkout)

and

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/dont-mess-magento-2-checkout/

But this does not work (for me at least). I don't know how to apply the:

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after-place-agreements') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

and I'm also not sure whether or not I applied the checkout_index_index.xml the right way (it does not change anything on my page):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="after-place-agreements" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/payment/before-place-order</item>
                                            </item>
                                                <item name="agreements" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, if this would work, this would only move the checkbox for the terms and conditions. In this topic, they talk about every 'place order' button to be declared in a different file each:

[Magento 2: Move place order button from payment to sidebar on checkout page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155010/magento-2-move-place-order-button-from-payment-to-sidebar-on-checkout-page)

Is there anyone who has a more comprehensive explanation of how to achieve all this?

I'm working on a custom module, so of course I don't want to overwrite any core files because the module has to be used on other Magento 2 instances too.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this step :

**=> Step 1:**

Create a `checkout_index_index.xml` file in :

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/layout path

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendorName_PlaceOrder::css/place_order_button.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PlaceOrder/js/view/summary</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PlaceOrder/summary</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**=> Step 2:**

Create a file `summary.html` in the path

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/web/template

```
<div class="opc-block-summary" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Order Summary'" class="title"></span>
    <!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- ko if: (isVisible()) -->
<div class="actions-toolbar-trigger" id="place-order-trigger-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="button action primary" id="place-order-trigger" value="Place Order" >
        <span>Place Order</span>
    </button>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**=> Step 3:**

Create a file summary.js in the path

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/web/js/view

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    ],
    function(
        $,
        ko,
        Component,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            isVisible: function () {
                return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
            },
            initialize: function () {
                $(function() {
                    $('body').on("click", '#place-order-trigger', function () {
                        $(".payment-method._active").find('.action.primary.checkout').trigger( 'click' );
                    });
                });
                var self = this;
                this._super();
            }

        });
    }
);
```

**=> Step 4 :**

For moving terms & condition checkbox in `checkout_index_index.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                    <item name="agreements" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
                                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                    </item>

                                                    <item name="agreements-validator" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/agreement-validation</item>
                                                    </item>

                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: In your answer you declare two `checkout_index_index.xml` files. One includes the summary.html and the other one moves the button. Do I have to combine theses two ?

Comment: These aren't actually steps, just pieces of code from the other Q/A.
This one is nice and ordered:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222416/validation-of-the-terms-and-conditions-custom-module
And this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155010/magento-2-move-place-order-button-from-payment-to-sidebar-on-checkout-page

Comment: How can I add Terms & Conditions checkout unde Flat rate shipping?